# Don't understand a power supply diagram of a microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, diagram

I'm not sure so I prefer to ask your opinion on this diagram:

[image]

Correct me if I'm wrong but I have the impression that DVDD12 is my voltage source of 1.2v and that the V1p2 label present on the right and left side, is in fact from the DVDD12 power supply with the BLM21PG221SN1D in series to power the pins on the right?

But if that's right, I don't understand why not calling V3p3, rather AVDD33, so we know that the two capital letters are the power source and the others are labels?

Being a beginner, I may be off the mark, you tell me! THANKS !

source : [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN91378_HX3_Hardware_Design_Guidelines_and_Schematic_Checklist-ApplicationNotes-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d073c6ed2607c)

Comment: I see your confusion. Even I thought DVDD12 is your external voltage source. However, I am not sure now after seeing the answer from fgrieu. It could be that V1p2 is your 1.2V voltage source in which case the naming is also consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data sheet states:
[image]

My reading of the note is:

- V3p3 is the 3.3V from your power source, and the mid left BLM21PG221SN1D is to purify that to make a cleaner 3.3V for pin 4.
- V1p2 is the 1.2V from your power source, and the top left BLM21PG221SN1D is to prevent noise originating from pins 1,3,19,27 to pollute V1p2 and other pins.

Per this reading of the note, DVDD12 is just a label to name the piece of copper material attached to pins 1,3,19,27, one side of some caps and one BLM21PG221SN1D (and to nothing else). The current would flow from your 1.2V power supply's output (V1p2) to DVDD12 thru that BLM21PG221SN1D.

I admit it could also be the other way around: your PSU to DVDD12, flowing to V1p2 thru the BLM21PG221SN1D, but that's not what the text in the note suggests to me. Also, drawings of power supply diagrams for the the FX3 series, like figure 3 [there](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN70707_EZ-USB_FX3_FX3S_SX3_hardware_design_guidelines_and_schematic_checklist-ApplicationNotes-v18_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d0739793e5dfd#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A16%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C40%2C248%2C0%5D), consistently use V1p2 or V1P2 for the output of the power supply (but on the other hand figure 6 has the V1P2 power supply directly to VDD, with chokes for the RX and TX sections).

Update: [This HX3 Kit](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-CY4609_HX3_Kit_User_Guide-UserManual-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0ef8f8a30eaa#G9.1140384) also uses V1p2 for the power supply output, and connects that directly to all except pins 1,3,19,27 which go thru a choke. That confirms my reading (and goes straight against the aforementioned figure 6).

Update: [This Optimized BOM design](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN94150_Designing_a_SuperSpeed_Hub_Using_HX3_with_Optimized_BOM-ApplicationNotes-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d073d6ceb61bc) also uses V1p2 for the power supply output, and connects all 1.2V nodes to that same piece of copper. As often, chokes are the first thing sacrificed to the BOM god (bulk caps are next).

Update: The [DC electrical characteristics](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/CYPR_S_A0010592712_1-3004548.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A112%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C44%2C574%2Cnull%5D) of the Data Sheet tells there's up to 526mA (410mA typ) drawn on the 1.2V, and the [power section](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/CYPR_S_A0010592712_1-3004548.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A116%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C44%2C694%2Cnull%5D) shows a lot of that is for the SuperSpeed transmit section (pins 7,13,37,43,49). A reason to have these pins directly to the 1.2V source could be that if instead the [BLM21PG221SN1D](https://www.murata.com/en-eu/api/pdfdownloadapi?cate=cgsubChipFerriBead&partno=BLM21PG221SN1%23) was in series on the SS Tx power source, the voltage drop across the 0.045Ω series resistance would be like -0.015V or -1.3%, enough to impact the transmission characteristics, which perhaps would impact USB conformance testing. IMHO there's less to fear with the corresponding voltage reduction on the core logic (both because logic is not as sensitive to such voltage drop, and because the current drawn likely is smaller).

Comment: I wonder what they mean by "compliance testing". Surely not EMC. USB or other interface compliance?

Comment: Yes, but if V1p2 is my power source, what is the DVDD12 label?

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit, the [CYUSB330x datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/CYPR_S_A0010592712_1-3004548.pdf) isn't very clear in this regard.

But when in doubt, always check for additional resources (e.g. evaluation or development boards).

The CYUSB3304 in fact has an evaluation board: [CY4609](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-CY4609_HX3_Kit_User_Guide-UserManual-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0ef8f8a30eaa)

The schematics show that **V3p3** and **V1p2** are your +3.3 V and +1.2 V power supplies, respectively.

[image]

In case of the +1.2 V core supply, pins 7, 13, 37, 43 and 49 are directly connected to your **V1p2** power supply. And the ferrite bead BLM21PG221SN1D is placed at the input of pins 1, 3, 19 and 27. The AVDD12 pins are also directly connected to your **V1p2**.

For the +3.3V power supply pins, the analog counterparts are behind the ferrite bead, while the digital power pins are connected to **V3p3**.

[image]

Comment: (Why on earth daisy chain the SC189 from 3.3 V instead of stepping down from 5 V?)

Comment: @greybeard I can only guess, but probably to reduce dissipated heat in the SC189. The 1.2V max total operation current is 526mA (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fPNu.png). (5V - 1.2V) * 526mA = 2W. While (3.3V - 1.2V) * 526mA = 1.1W. The additional load on AOZ1021AI doesn't have the same impact.

Comment: (Voltage difference times current looks valid for linear regulators. For buck with internal "off-time switch", input voltage should change switching losses, only, leaving conduction losses unchanged (with external "off-time switch" conduction losses should *decrease*), and the SC189 is spec'ed for 1.5 A.)

Comment: @greybeard Yes, you're correct. I only read 'Regulator' and assumed a linear regulator without looking closely.

Comment: @greybeard And since there is no power sequencing requirement (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfBjt.png), which would've been my next guess, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @fgrieu The datasheet refers to DVDD12 as '1.2V core supply' (the entirety of all DVDD12 pins): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDHcw.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAFBb.png. Only the user guide splits them further: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8ecw.png

Comment: Yes. But [Table 3 of AN91378](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-AN91378_HX3_Hardware_Design_Guidelines_and_Schematic_Checklist-ApplicationNotes-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7cdc391c017d073c6ed2607c#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A23%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C51%2C336%2C0%5D) shows pins 7, 13, 37, 43 and 49 are what powers the USB3 SuperSpeed Tx section, rather than the rest of the "core" . Granted it's still used the same name DVDD12, which is confusing. That's probably to align with the data sheet, which is lacking on this distinction.

Comment: @fgrieu I agree. On another note: how did you manage to generate an URL which links directly to that specific section? I'm following [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1384892/how-to-create-url-link-to-the-specific-section-of-the-pdf-file) on Super User. If you want to answer there I can upvote your answser and it might benefit others.